# IOS dev:Problem UIMoreNavigationController and ABPeoplePickerNavigationController

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4

i'm using ios SDK 4.3.5 and an iphone 3GS.
i created a tabbar with more than 5 items, so that automatically the last item tabbar generates more button with it's view, the problem is that one of these elements added in UIMoreViewController is a subclass of ABPeoplePickerNavigationController and when I try to enter that view make me the following error, but this error comes only when in sight UIMoreViewController not when in the tabBarController:

```
2011-08-15 12:48:59.331 SmartMobile[768:707] -[UIMoreNavigationController bannerTitle]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x4b5820
2011-08-15 12:48:59.408 SmartMobile[768:707] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIMoreNavigationController bannerTitle]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x4b5820'
*** Call stack at first throw:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x33f5f64f __exceptionPreprocess + 114
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x310dcc5d objc_exception_throw + 24
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x33f631bf -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 102
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x33f62649 ___forwarding___ + 508
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x33ed9180 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 48
    5   AddressBookUI                       0x31f7bba7 -[ABMembersViewController loadView] + 74
    6   UIKit                               0x325e7ebf -[UIViewController view] + 30
    7   UIKit                               0x325f65ef -[UIViewController contentScrollView] + 22
    8   UIKit                               0x325f645f -[UINavigationController _computeAndApplyScrollContentInsetDeltaForViewController:] + 30
    9   UIKit                               0x325f635d -[UINavigationController _layoutViewController:] + 24
    10  UIKit                               0x325f5db7 -[UINavigationController _startTransition:fromViewController:toViewController:] + 254
    11  UIKit                               0x325f5c43 -[UINavigationController _startDeferredTransitionIfNeeded] + 182
    12  UIKit                               0x325e7d5d -[UINavigationController pushViewController:transition:forceImmediate:] + 640
    13  UIKit                               0x325e7ad3 -[UINavigationController pushViewController:animated:] + 34
    14  UIKit                               0x326203c1 -[UIMoreNavigationController pushViewController:animated:] + 48
    15  UIKit                               0x32739721 -[UIMoreListController tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:] + 84
    16  UIKit                               0x3260551b -[UITableView _selectRowAtIndexPath:animated:scrollPosition:notifyDelegate:] + 662
    17  UIKit                               0x326690eb -[UITableView _userSelectRowAtPendingSelectionIndexPath:] + 130
    18  Foundation                          0x331686d5 __NSFireDelayedPerform + 368
    19  CoreFoundation                      0x33f36a47 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_TIMER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 14
    20  CoreFoundation                      0x33f38ecb __CFRunLoopDoTimer + 850
    21  CoreFoundation                      0x33f39845 __CFRunLoopRun + 1088
    22  CoreFoundation                      0x33ec9ec3 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 230
    23  CoreFoundation                      0x33ec9dcb CFRunLoopRunInMode + 58
    24  GraphicsServices                    0x31bf441f GSEventRunModal + 114
    25  GraphicsServices                    0x31bf44cb GSEventRun + 62
    26  UIKit                               0x325dfd69 -[UIApplication _run] + 404
    27  UIKit                               0x325dd807 UIApplicationMain + 670
    28  SmartMobile                         0x0000ee04 main + 140
    29  SmartMobile                         0x000022c4 start + 40
)
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'NSException'
Program received signal:  “SIGABRT”.
```

in advance thank you very much and I hope someone can help me

Comment: What is the method 'bannerTitle' meant to do?

Comment: Precisely that is the problem, uiMoreNavigation is a class that automatically adds the ios sdk, is not documented class even in ios library developer, so I have no idea why it does not work, not like this implemented, or referred to bannerTitle, for that reason if someone else had a similar problem, help!!